# How to create a kotlin data class constructor with several same params?

Tags: android, kotlin, constructor, data-class

Basically I have this:

```
constructor() : this(null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null)
```

and I would like some like

```
constructor() : this(null)
```

Or even something like this

```
constructor() : this(null...)//java like
```

Is this achievable?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The thing you marked as "Java like" doesn't exist in Java to my knowledge.

The expected way to do this in Kotlin is to use parameter defaults:

```
class Foo(val name: String? = null, val address: String? = null)
```

Now you can call the constructor without any arguments and it will use the default values you specified with `=` for the ones you omit.

If you need to use it from Java or with some library that instantiates it via empty constructor, then you can use `@JvmOverloads` so it generates the empty constructor (along with some other combinations, [see the documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/-jvm-overloads/)). Note, this is unnecessary if *all* parameters of the primary constructor have default values. In such case, the empty constructor is automatically generated.

```
class Foo @JvmOverloads constructor(val name: String? = null, val address: String? = null)
```

Comment: Hmm, are you sure it generates every possible combination of parameters? I believe it "only" creates ctors for first N params, so: no params, only first param, first two params and so on. You don't get a ctor for providing a second param, but not providing the first one. Number of ctors are number of params + 1.

Comment: @broot You're right. I remembered it wrong.